# difficulty in loading huge matrices using numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am working on a FUJITSU system with Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5-2637 v4 @ 3.50GHz × 16 processor and 64 GB RAM. The python version is 2.7.12.

I am trying to load a matrix of size  38756 X 38756 (around 12 GB memory) using numpy.loadtxt command. It is taking a lot of time. There are 6 such matrices which I try to load using a for loop and the system sometimes hangs.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you can use pyspark to load.

Comment: Often data in a text file on disk requires much more RAM to load into a typed format like NumPy array. (E.g. '1' in the text file might be a single byte, but NumPy might allocate 8 bytes to store it in an int64 array)

Comment: For this type of data, you must look at storage alternatives. [Blosc](https://github.com/Blosc) or HDF5 with [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/) are good candidates. If you insist on loading the data from a plain text file you would probably have a better chance with successive partial readings (i.e. cut the file in 32 or 128 subparts, for instance), declaring an empty array first (`np.empty((Nx, Ny))`)